# Не добавляются записи в БД(MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Код подключения :

```
<?php 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','forum');
if($mysqli == FALSE)
   {
     echo "БД не подключенно!<br/>".mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 ?>
```

Код страницы добавления записи :

```
<?php
function fail($str){
    echo "Неправильно указан(о) $str";
    exit();
}
//Проверка
if(isset($_POST['button'])){

if(!empty(trim($_POST['name']))){
$name = $_POST['name'];
}else{fail(" имя");}

if(!empty(trim($_POST['tema']))){
$tema = $_POST['tema'];
}else{fail(" тема");}

if(!empty(trim($_POST['text']))){
$text = $_POST['text'];
}else{fail(" текст");}    


require ("BD/mysqli_connect.php");//Add connect with BD - Mysqli
$add_message = mysqli_query($mysqli , "INSERT INTO comment (author,tema,message,pubdate) VALUES ('$name' , '$tema' , '$text' , NOW())");
}


 ?>
<form action="/set_message.php" method="POST">
    <p><p>Имя : <input type="name" name="name"></p>
    <p>Тема : <input type="text" name="tema"></p>
    <p>Текст : <input type="text" name="text"><br/></p></p>

    <button type="submit" name="button"><p>Отправить</p></button>
</form>
<p><a href="index.php">Вернутьcя на форум</a></p>
```

Comment: здравствуйте, sql injection

Comment: Умно , ничего не скажешь .

Comment: это намек на то, как делать не нужно. Какую ошибку Вы получаете ? Что скажет `printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));` после строки `$add_message = mysqli_query ... ` ?

Comment: Я понял в чем ошибка , она собственно - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value , спасибо тебе!

Comment: пожалуйста) а вот так `INSERT INTO comment (author,tema,message,pubdate) VALUES ('$name' , '$tema' , '$text' , NOW())` никогда не делайте, используйте подготовленные выражения.

Comment: если проблемы больше нет, рекомендую удалить ответ, т.к. вряд ли он кому-либо будет полезен, или же Вы можете написать ответ.

Comment: капец я протупил , просто нужно указать авто-инкремент , а столько проблем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После выполнения кода выбивает ошибка:

> Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Для её исправление в БД ячейке `id` поставьте галочку на A_I - Авто-инкремент

Так при каждой записи в БД `id` автоматически указывает себе значение.